# Size allocated for parameters sent to a method

Tags: c++, windows, parameters, memory-management

Is there a way to know what is size of the allocated space for the parameters sent to a function if I know its frame pointer and return address?
(preferably without using debug symbols)

Comment: What kind of parameter ? Is it dynamically allocated pointer or just some object ?

Comment: I think the OP is asking if he can work out the size of all the paramters..  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I need to know where the stack frame of that method ends and it ends after the space allocated for the passed in parameters...

Comment: And do you need to know this while inside the function?

Comment: I'm actually looking at it from the outside. like a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. For a start, you don't know the calling convention so you have no idea how the parameters were passed and who is supposed to clean them up.  Even if you do know the calling convention I don't believe there is a fool proof way to determine what you ask for.

Comment: Debuggers must do this, presumably they do have extra information stored about the parameters in the symbols?

Comment: @Benj Debuggers typically have debug information. But they don't need to know about the size of the space allocated to parameters, whatever that means.

Comment: But I don't care about how it is passed or its intenral order, I jusr want to know its size.

Comment: @David Debuggers can usually print out the values of all the parameters in any given stack frame, presumably they therefore need to know how big all of them are while unwinding each frame...

Comment: @ldov - In some calling conventions (win32 64 bit for example), parameters are partially passed on registers rather than the stack, which means the parameters are not available to even a debugger...  You would need to know the calling convention to be able to allow for this when working out the offset produced on the stack..

Comment: I suspect that with some calling conventions it would be possible and with others it would be impossible to do as David says...

Comment: @benj: It's ok, I'm only intersted in the things exists in the stack.

Comment: @Benj: Debuggers know that because of debug symbols. Without symbols, debuggers have to do a bit of guesswork via `EBP`. They often guess wrong and you get an incomplete stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

you usually see functions like;

```
myFunction(char* buffer, int bufferSize, ...) { ... }
```

without sending the size as a second parameter (or in a structure), you cannot determine the allocated space. but if this is a string or another byte array with a significant delimiter, you can check for the size (not for the allocated space).

edit: to get parameter sizes, you need to use `va_list`, `va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end` library functions.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_list/

Comment: it's ok, if the function is something like: foo(char* buffer), I except to get the result = 4 (the size of the pointer)

Comment: i see. then that should be you starting point. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_list/

Comment: @Idov:  That parameter may be passed in a register, or it could be that all parameter passing is done aligned to an 8-byte boundary, or something like that.  Nor is the size of a pointer 4 on all common architectures.

Answer (score 0):

If all the data is allocated on the stack, then for a function foo(par1, par2, ..., par10) the size of parameters par1, ..., par9 should be ((long) &par10) - ((long) &par1).

You can add a dummy parameter at the end of the parameter list and this would allow you to determine the size of all the real parameters.